# v-for dynamic component vuejs 1.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to dynamic load vue components with v-for?

```
  data: {
    "components" : [
      {"type": "my-first"},
      {"type": "my-second"}
    ]
  }

<component v-for="com in components" is="com.type"></component>
```

[Full example](https://jsbin.com/dasecanesa/6/edit?html,output)

I have seen an example with v-repeat but this is deprecated in Vue 1.0.
[link](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/254#issuecomment-121279001)

Comment: yes it is possible. refer to https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2424

Answer (score 1):

It needed the right data binding `:is="com.type"`

[link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2424#issuecomment-192705832)